# How to send messages with Firebase admin SDK

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Nuget used:

FireBaseAdmin v1.9.2

I'm trying to use firebase admin to send push notification to fcm.
I read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) but can't find any other good source to figure out how to use it properly. 
I can't figure out where to add the serverkey and senderid.

I made a methode for sending push notifications. 
Has anyone an example i could follow or any other documentation?

```
public override async Task<string> Send(List<String> tokens, string title, string body)
{
   var message = Message()
   {
      Tokens = tokens,
      Notification = new Notification()
      {
         Title = title,
         Body = body
      }
   };

   return await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

When i debug this code the response is null from SendAsync.
It might be because i didn't give it the serverkey and senderId but then i would expect an error like serverKeyNotFound.

Comment: If you already suspect what the cause of the problem is, did you try fixing it by specifying the server key and sender ID?

Comment: I think its because i haven't created a FirebaseApp https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup and assign it a private server key. I coudn't find in the documentation where i could specify it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server key and sender ID parameters are not used in the Admin SDK. You just need to instantiate a `FirebaseApp` with some `GoogleCredential` as shown in https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup.

On top of that your code seems to be syntactically incorrect. There's no `Tokens` property available in the [`Message`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/messaging/message) class. You need `MulticastMessage` class for that. So I'd expect the above code to fail compilation.

Comment: Hey, can you provide a good example where firstly we create tokens for the web and send notifications. I can't find one.